# Модификация файла после загрузки перед сохранением модели (смена кодировки, django)

Tags: python, django

Имеется поле модельки типа `FileField`, куда в моем конкретном случае заливаются файлы `html`.

Часто заливаются файлы не той кодировки(по инструкции надо `utf8`, а заливают `cp1251`) - сейчас они хранятся как есть и при выдаче конвертируются на лету.

Мне кажется, что было бы правильно конвертить их сразу после заливки.

В какаю сторону копать ?

Comment: Возможно стоит посмотреть на сигналы https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/ (а конкретно на `pre_save`).

Comment: в FileField хранится только путь к файлу, а не сам файл.

Comment: Возможно не стоит перекладывать на пользователя. Определяйте кодировку перед отдачей и конвертируйте, или отлавивайте ошибку и конвертируйте на сервере.